# For which finite groups is the Frattini subgroup equal to the "Baer Radical" (intersection of all maximal normal subgroups?)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I've always thought that the intersection of conjugates of a maximal subgroup of a finite group $G$ is maximal as a normal subgroup, but I've since deduced (via sledgehammer) that this cannot be true.

Can someone give an example where this is not true?

Is there a characterization of finite groups for which its Frattini subgroup is actually the intersection of all maximal normal subgroups?

Comment: How about the Klein $4$-group?

Comment: @DerekHolt I don't see how that's an example. In any abelian group the maximal subgroups are also maximal normal...

Comment: You said the "intersection of conjugates of maximal subgroups" which is trivial. Did you mean the intersection of the conjugates of a single maximal subgroup? If so, you really should make that clear! You wrote "maximal subgroups" not "a maximal subgroup".

Comment: @DerekHolt Aha yes I see now how that was confusing. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Let $G=S_3$. Then a Sylow $2$-subgroup is maximal and the intersection of its conjugates is trivial, but the trivial subgroup is not maximal normal because there is a normal subgroup of order $3$.

Comment: Any chance you know of any references that discuss the difference between the Frattini subgroup and the "Baer radical"? Googling "baer radical or jacobson radical" turns up mostly results about rings/modules.

Comment: Btw, the reason I'm asking, is roughly due to my interest in: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/224056/abelian-and-nonabelian-parts-of-aut-widehatf-2  If $\Delta$ is the class of finite groups all of whose composition factors are nonabelian, then I can prove that there is a surjective map $\widehat{F_2}\rightarrow\widehat{F_2}^\Delta\times\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}^2$ with kernel contained in the Baer radical of $\widehat{F_2}$. I first I thought the Baer radical is the Frattini subgroup, but apparently the Frattini subgroup for $\widehat{F_2}$ is trivial, and $\widehat{F_2}$ is not a direct product

Comment: ...so for $\widehat{F_2}$, its Baer radical can't be equal to its Frattini subgroup, which basically means that there exist finite groups such that all 2-generated extensions of it have their Baer radical not equal to their Frattini subgroup. Anyway, intuitively, the Baer radical should be *small*. I'd like to understand exactly how "small" it is. Unfortunately I don't know of any good references for this Baer radical (also called the Jacobson radical).